# Travis CI has failures on unchanged code for pull request

Tags: travis-ci, apache-flink

I submitted my first pull request to the Apache Flink project on github, but the Travis CI check is saying two of the tests it ran have failed. The thing is that where it says the failures are occurring is in a module that I haven't modified at all. So what am I missing? I am very new to Travis CI as well, so I could just be reading something the wrong way, but I doubt it.

Here is the pull request on Travis CI: https://travis-ci.org/apache/flink/builds/368327990

The module I made changes to was Flink-connector-cassandra and the failure is happening in the module flink.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually such problems should be asked on the `dev@` mailing list of the corresponding project and not on Stackoverflow. Sometimes builds are not stable and thus tests might fail even though you have nothing to do with them. In most cases there exists already an issue in the corresponding bug tracker that mentions the test instability. If the community says everything is fine, you can still open your PR.

However, in your case you have "Too many files with unapproved license" which clearly indicates a mistake on your side. You need to add an Apache License header to your newly created files.

Comment: Thanks twalthr. I will keep future questions of this nature to their mailing list.